# Join ZOOM meeting not able to join participants NodeJS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, zoom-sdk

I was able to setup this sample of Web SDK from zoom itself.

https://zoom.github.io/sample-app-web/

[image]

It's working fine. I can join to the meeting. However if the meeting already started and first participant joined meeting. The other participant won't be able to join and will return an error.

Is that because, I'm just using 1 pair of API KEY and Secret Key?

My goal is, to join multiple participants using 1 pair of API and Secret Key

**UPDATE**

This happens when trying to join multiple role.

Example: You can join, role attendee **(role == 0)** and host **(role == 1)** at the same time. But while if you try to join another attendee but different email or name it will not allow you to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, I'm using pro-plan. Support suggested to upgrade my plan to Business OR Education Plan.

To fix the problem.

As per my investigation it's because I'm using 1 api key from my account.